# Cannot push any files due to refspec issue while trying to upload problems to GitHub

Tags: git, github

there. I am creating a basic website with files and folders I need inside a GitHub repo. I have tried extensively to push these files, but, I get the error that my authentication is invalid even though my username and password are correct. Furthermore, sometimes, it gives me the error that the "remote origin already exists." I want to push these files to my existing repo, "webapp." Also, below, I deleted my name for obvious reasons but provided the output and all the things I have done.

1. `git init`

**`Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/someone/PycharmProjects/allprojects/webpage/.git/`**

---

2. `$ git commit -m "first commit"`

**`On branch main nothing to commit, working tree clean`**

---

3. `$ git remote add origin https://github.com/rishp66/webapp.git`

**`fatal: remote origin already exists.`**

---

4. `git push -u origin main`

---

***Output:***

Username for 'https://github.com': ...

Password for 'https://...@github.com':

- remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
- remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
- fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/rishp66/webapp.git/'

##### I tried doing this with a personal access token as well for sometime as a password but that was invalid as well. Below are also logs of my previous commmits.

`$ git log`

`commit 7dd2cb6954cf55f40ffc0c624f0d569ff23eab42 (HEAD -> main)`

`Author: N/A <my_email>`

`Date:   Sat Feb 4 18:42:00 2023 -0500`

```
first
```

`commit 3bfbc0bc134a9d9bc885f19936894322ac7bf8b0`
`Author: N/A <my_email>`
`Date:   Sat Feb 4 17:23:25 2023 -0500`

```
initial commit
```

Comment: You probably have to use ssh keys instead and set your remote url to `git@github.com:user/repo.git`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already properly set up your ssh credentials, you can change your **existing** remote url to a git-ssh version using `git remote set-url`. For example:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:rishp66/webapp.git
```